# Echo a html phrase, with onclick function

Tags: php, html, onclick, echo

Hello dear programmers,

I have a problem with the echoing of a html phrase with an onclick function that executes a javascript function. I want to build a tabpage, for a image gallery.

The echo:

```
 echo "<div class='albumitem'><a class='tablinks' onclick='openAlbum(event, '".$album."')'><h1 class='galleryheader'>".$album."</h1></a><div id='".$album."' class='tabcontent'>";
```

Everything goes well, except the passing of the variable in the onclick function, as you can see here. What actually the HTML looks like:

```
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openAlbum(event, " aubing')'=""><h1 class="galleryheader">Aubing</h1></a>
```

But this onclick event has to look like this:

```
onclick="openAlbum(event, 'Aubing')"
```

Is there a way to actually realise this or do I have to find an other option?
I actually tried switching " with ', didnt go very well....

Thank you for everybody that tries to help

Comment: Seems fine to me, if the output is wrong the content of the variable is most likely not what you expect, try doing a `var_dump($album)` and see if it is a string 'Aubing' - **edit** i see what you mean, your using `'` inside `'` so they would indeed need escaping like Sir McPotato said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<div class='albumitem'><a class='tablinks' onclick='openAlbum(event, \"$album\")'><h1 class='galleryheader'>".$album."</h1></a><div id='".$album."' class='tabcontent'>";
```

see escaped double quotes in the `onclick` definition

Comment: Thank you Bhaskar, helped me a lot=D Now I can finish that

Comment: Glad to help you. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

**addslashes** is what you are looking exactly.And also you have to remove the single quotes in variable.Try to do the following way.

```
echo "<div class='albumitem'><a class='tablinks' onclick='openAlbum(event, '".addslashes($album)."')'><h1 class='galleryheader'>".$album."</h1></a><div id=".addslashes($album)." class='tabcontent'>";
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the variable needs to be coverd in ' with your addslashes() command it gives me this: `onclick="openAlbum(event, Aubing)"`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
$escapedString = htmlspecialchars('This is a test string: < > & \' " end.', ENT_COMPAT);
echo "<div onclick='alert(this.dataset.name)' data-name=\"$escapedString\">Click Me</div>";
```

This approach avoid quotes inside function, no quotes nesting.